# How to display images with google facets dive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, visualization, facet

I am getting started with google facets, but I am finding the documentation insufficient.

I want to use facets dive to visualize images like they do [here](https://ai.googleblog.com/2017/07/facets-open-source-visualization-tool.html) for *cifar-10* . There is another example [here](https://pair-code.github.io/facets/quickdraw.html) using the *Quick, draw!* dataset.

However, I cannot find how to set it up.

That is about what I have so far, the code works all right:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

#load data:
mnist = fetch_mldata("MNIST original")
idx =np.random.randint(70000, 1000) #get random 1000 samples
X = mnist.data[idx]/255.0
y = mnist.target[idx]

#dimensionality reduction to get 3 features
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
pca_result = pca.fit_transform(X)

#put everything in a dataframe
df = df_pca = pd.DataFrame(data = pca_result, columns = [["pca-one", "pca-two", "pca-three"]])
df['y'] = y

#display facets dive
jsonstr = df.to_json(orient='records')
HTML_TEMPLATE = """<link rel="import" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PAIR-code/facets/master/facets-dist/facets-jupyter.html">
        <facets-dive id="elem" height="600"></facets-dive>
        <script>
          var data = {jsonstr};
          document.querySelector("#elem").data = data;
        </script>"""
html = HTML_TEMPLATE.format(jsonstr=jsonstr)
display(HTML(html))
```

This script works fine, but I just get circles with the labels (or whichever feature I choose), but I don't see how to integrate the actual images in there. The only hint I have so far is that I need the [facets_atlasmaker](https://github.com/PAIR-code/facets/tree/master/facets_atlasmaker) for that, but I found the documentation rather insufficient.

If something is not clear, please let me know in the comments, I can try do add more relevant information then.